# Get current data in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have a table, in mysql and it has a column called Date.. I want to take from the database all the rows with date the same as current date. How can I do this? please help me.

I am trying like below:

```
$sql=mysql_query(select * from table where Date=getCurrentDate());
```

But it does not function..Please help me

I update my code like this:

```
$aktivitetet=mysql_query("select * from aktiviteti where Date=CURDATE())");

$rai=mysql_num_rows($aktivitetet);

if($rai>0)
{echo"There are activities on that date";}
else
{echo "There are no activities";}
```

but I have this error: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\agenda\home.php on line 125

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `date` column is of the `date` type, use [`CURDATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate)

```
$sql=mysql_query(select * from table where Date=CURDATE());
```

If that column is a `datetime` type use [`Date()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date), too:

```
$sql=mysql_query(select * from table where Date(`Date`)=CURDATE());
```

Comment: the column type is DATE

Comment: What does that error mean : Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\agenda\home.php on line 125? I update my code like above

Comment: Means your query failed. Are you sure that data type is correct? Column names, too?

Comment: Can you post the actual query here?

Comment: I posted it above....If I use it like here :$aktivitetet=mysql_query("select * from aktiviteti where Date='12-12-2014'") it works...but like above dont work...what can I do?

Comment: That looks ok to me. Try wrapping the Date column name in ticks and see if that changes anything.

Comment: By using this Date='CURDATE()', the error is gone..BUt can I save the date in the form 2014-02-12, because with the format 12-02-2014, it said to me that there is no activity on this date... I notice this by trying with concrete dates...

Comment: MySQL expects the date to be in YYYY-MM-DD format. As long as you use that format this will work and working with dates in MySQL will be easy.

Comment: but id does not work...it say to me that there in no activity on this date, while in fact I have activity registered on 2014-02-14, ane if I use Date='2014-02-14',it said that there is an activity....what can I do?Please help

Comment: Can I ask you for something else? what about if I want rows with current date, but also 30 minutes before current time? Should I use: $aktivitetet=mysql_query("select * from aktiviteti where Data=CURDATE() and Perd_Id='$perdoruesi and  Ora=CURTIME()'"); But how to make calculation with CURTIME

Comment: If your column is of the `date` type you won't be able to do that because the time is not stored for you to search against. You would need to change the data type to `datetime` which also includes the time. Then you can use DATE_SUB() to do this.

Comment: No I have another column called Ora wich is the type : time. And Iwant to use this column to test for the time.. I use the column Date only for date...for the time I use column Ora, like in comment above. Is it possible in this case?

Comment: Yes. Something like `AND Ora > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)`

Comment: I tried it , but it always show me the activity even it is more or less then 30 minutes from now....I want to calculate only the activities that are less than 30 minutes from now

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a string to the mysql_query method:

```
$sql=mysql_query('select * from table where Date=CURDATE()');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$now = new DateTime();
$now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');    // MySQL datetime format
$now->getTimestamp();

$sql=mysql_query("select * from table where Date=".$now);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just incase you have only just started developing your application you should look into using **mysqli** instead of mysql (mysql will be gone as of php 5.5.0). If not you should just be able to use "Date=CURDATE".

---

$link = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE Date=CURDATE()" or die("Error" . mysqli_error($link));

$result = $link->query($query);

while($row = mysqli_fecth_array($result)) {
  echo $row["Date"] . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check your "Date" type is it the same type with the current date type that you get from "getCurrentDate()" function, you will need to set your Date format for your convenience.